# Ajax Post and Redirect with Model Value MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I am submitting a page through agax post with json data and then redirecting to other view. It's working fine.

```
 $.ajax({
            url: '/bus/result',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: ko.toJSON(bookingInfo),
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                window.location.href = data.redirectToUrl;
            }
        });
```

MVC Controller

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Result(BusBookingInfo bookingInfo)
        {
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return Json(new { redirectToUrl = Url.Action("Booking") });
            }

            //return Redirect("/bus/booking/");
            return RedirectToAction("result");
        }
```

But now I wanted to pass bookingInfo object to Booking view. I know I can pass through query string but is possible to bind this model object booking view?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `window.location.href` in success callback,

```
success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
    window.location.href = data.redirectToUrl;
}
```

You can make another `ajax`/`$.post` call here, and pass your object using `POST` method.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/bus/result',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: ko.toJSON(bookingInfo),
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            $.post(data.redirectToUrl, bookingInfo, function(){
               //TODO: callback
            });
        }
    });
```

**Update:**
Perhaps TempData dictioanry can be helpful here...

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Result(BusBookingInfo bookingInfo)
{
   if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
   {
     TempData["ViewModelItem"] = bookingInfo;
     return RedirectToAction("Booking");
   }
   //return Redirect("/bus/booking/");
   return RedirectToAction("result");
}        

public ActionResult Booking()
{
   var bookingInfo = (BusBookingInfo)TempData["ViewModelItem"];
   //TODO: code
}
```

Comment: But it's not landing on other view if I will remove that line.

Comment: You can do it in `.$post` success callback. `window.location.href = data.redirectToUrl;` where I commented `//TODO`

Comment: no success. I want to pass the same data bookingInfo to next view. As you suggested it posting the data on the next view.

Comment: Thanks, I already implemented this workaround. But I am feeling this is not a right solution. Anyway thanks for your all information.