# render page with model after ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to make an ajax post request, and in the controller return a model, after which the page is rendered with that model? To illustrate what I mean, say we have a simple ajax post:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Home/PostReq",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    dataType: "html",
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    error: function (jqXHR, error, errorThrown) {
        //display error
    }
})
```

And in the Home Controller I have:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostReq(MyModel model)
{ 
    //do some changes to model
    //render view with new model
    return View(model);
}
```

How do I achieve this? At the moment, this does nothing, the page doesn't refresh or re-render itself. Is it possible to do this from an ajax request?

The reason I am using ajax but not using a model to bind the form data is because it's dynamic and as I understand I cannot dynamically bind form data to the model.

Comment: would this not be better done server side on preRender? (or some other asp.net lifecycle event)

Comment: I'm totally confused by this question. So you've made a request to the PostReq action, and inside the PostReq view want to call it again? With the same model? Will this not be recursive anyway?

Comment: Return the model instead of actionresult and handle it in the succes callback of the $.ajax

Comment: @JayMee I want to be able to redirect to a new page (or same page if there are form errors) after the post request. In doing so, I want to be able to pass a modified version of the model to the view, and have it re-rendered. Does that make more sense?

Comment: @SherinMathew how can I do that? I want to be able to re-render the page with the same (modified) model, so how can I make it bind?

Comment: @atmd I am unfamiliar with what you said - perhaps you can provide some article?

Answer (score 4):

Add a `success` callback to your `$.ajax`, this will provide you with the result of the post (in this case the html), something like:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/PostReq",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        dataType: "html",
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        error: function (jqXHR, error, errorThrown) {
            //display error
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $("body").html(data);
        }
    })
```

This would be easier with a partialview rather than replacing the whole body.

Answer (score 3):

Yes ofcourse it can be done. There are few things to keep in mind

**1)**  First of all the returned View after post should be a Partial View not Full View

**2)** You have to put a container div on your main View where the response partial view from ajax call will be appended is success callback.

I mean is, in your main view you will have:

```
<div id="container">
<div>
```

and in ajax call success function append response in the container div like:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/Home/PostReq",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            error: function (jqXHR, error, errorThrown) {
                //display error
            }
            success: function(response) {

              $('#container').html(response);
             }
        })
```

Comment: what if I want to redirect to a different view?

Comment: or if I want to do model binding after the post, I can't do that with ajax

Comment: in that case you have to return url from server side as json and redirect from client side using ``window.location.href=url``

Comment: Alright, so if I redirect from client side, how can I also pass the model?

Comment: you can do, the view you will return should be strongly typed with model in that case

Comment: there are couple of ways

Comment: Could you suggest some articles on how to do that? I have just tried a few approaches now but with no success

Comment: I tried this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17315183/3281466 but it doesn't end up re-directing. The only way I could get it to work was with window.location.replace(url) but that obviously doesn't allow me to pass the model data

Comment: check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648780/how-to-redirect-to-new-pagealong-with-model-on-jquery-ajax-call-in-mvc3