# Render part of template doesn't apply css using ajax (flask back-end)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

Why I can not apply css file when render part of template?

I have studied [render page with model after ajax post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592702/render-page-with-model-after-ajax-post/30592921#30592921)
, for now I know I can return part of html file into specific div which is in certain html

---

My problem, example:

There are 2 html file names
**father.html** and **children.html**, I want to fill **children.html** into a div tag in **father.html**, its OK for me! But why tags in **children.html** couldn't apply css(setup on **father.css**)

**father.html** has its own external file **father.css** and **father.js**

For father.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/father.css') }}">
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/father.js') }}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <!-- @@@ children.html here!! Using AJAX @@@ -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

For father.js

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/returnChildrenTemplate',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#container').html(data); // return template into container
    }
})
```

For father.css

```
canvas {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

For children.html:

```
<table>
{% for r in data %}
<tr>
    <td> {{ r.id }} </td>
    <td> 
        <canvas class="demo" style="background-color: {{r.color }} "></canvas>
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

For back-end flask script:

```
@app.router('/returnChildrenTemplate')
def returnChildrenTemplate():
    result = ... # query from Database
    return render_template('children.html', data=result)
```

It doesn't work for children.html, its canvas tag is still its original size.

It works if I set canvas style into **children.html**. ( It quite stupid)

```
<head>
    <style>
        canvas {
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<table>
...
((  the same as above ))
...
</table>
```

What is this issue? Is there any method to solve this ?

BTW, father.js has the same problem.

Comment: Can you post the WHOLE content of children.html? Is it including an <iframe>, and <html> element or similar?

Comment: @Maluen It's my whole children.html.   
I didn't use iframe and anything special tag

Comment: It might be that `css/father.css` isn't being loaded at all, try to add a rule to it to change the background color of the document or check via devtools to see if the file is being loaded correctly.

Comment: Thanks. For now, I just write CSS and JS rules into children.html